# d3.js Map worked fine until used in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, d3.js

I've created a d3 Map which works fine in a standalone html file - locally and on a live website but now it's been added into a work-in-progress theme, it stops when it hits the d3.json line.

d3 is working as the initial SVG and divs are created properly, but the actions within the d3.json function are now not running (though nothing I can see has changed). The same wordpress template file renamed .html and opened locally still works fine (php ignored).

Is there any reason why this d3 visualisation is failing? Here's the start of the d3.json..

```
// build the globe
d3.json("https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.json", (error, world) => {
    if (error) { 
        console.log("%cMap d3.json error:", "color: red; font-weight: bold;");
        throw error;
    };
    // draw the land using TOPOJSON package
    var land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land);

    // d3 flat map projection
    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(339)
        .translate( [width / 2, height / 1.45]);

    // create projection of flat earth
    var path = d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection);

    // draw countries
    var earth = g.append("path")
        .datum(land)
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", "#4b4f53");
```

I'm not able to share the wordpress as it's not live, but here is the **working** map: https://mikechalmers.co.uk/map/ and here is the version on worpress (with styling and php / ACF parts removed for brevity)

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>

<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

// d3 world map by Mike Chalmers https://mikechalmers.co.uk 2022

// margin calculations
const width = 1440,
    height = 1440;
let viewBox = "0 0 " + height + " " + width;

// add an SVG to the body and a g group
var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", viewBox)
    .classed("svg-content", true);
var g = svg.append("g");

// add a div for the hover popups
var officePop = d3.select("#map").append("div")
    .attr("class", "office-popup")
    .style("opacity", 0)
var officePopImage = officePop.append("img")
    .attr("class", "office-popup-image")
    .attr("src", "https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch")
var officePopTitle = officePop.append("div")
    .attr("class", "office-popup-title")
    .text("City")

// build the globe
d3.json("https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.json", (error, world) => {
    // draw the land using TOPOJSON package
    var land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land);

    // d3 flat map projection
    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(339)
        .translate( [width / 2, height / 1.45]);

    // create projection of flat earth
    var path = d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection);

    // draw countries
    var earth = g.append("path")
        .datum(land)
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("fill", "#4b4f53");

    // list of locations - reverse the lat / long numbers as Google present them!
    var locale = [
        [31.2273214, 30.0352233, "Cairo", "https://placeimg.com/501/501/arc", "http://act.is"], // Cairo
        [18.0942349,-33.9142626, "Cape Town", "https://placeimg.com/620/580/arc", "http://act.is"], // Cape Town
        [76.812386, 28.6466758, "Delhi", "https://placeimg.com/440/480/arc", "http://act.is"], // Delhi
        [54.9468679, 25.0757582, "Dubai", "https://placeimg.com/640/444/arc", "http://act.is"], // Dubai
        [113.9872706, 22.3526629, "Hong Kong", "https://placeimg.com/500/500/arc", "http://act.is"], // Hong Kong
        [27.9698125, -26.1715045, "Johannesburg", "https://placeimg.com/600/380/arc", "http://act.is"], // Johannesburg
        [3.3983055, 6.4628925, "Lagos", "https://placeimg.com/390/380/arc", "http://act.is"], // Lagos
        [-0.2420245, 51.5285578, "London", "https://placeimg.com/620/422/arc", "http://act.is"], // London
        [5.5715358, 49.8139418, "Luxembourg", "https://placeimg.com/633/430/arc", "http://act.is"], // Luxembourg
        [39.7423519, -20.2030759, "Mauritius", "https://placeimg.com/700/780/arc", "http://act.is"], // Mauritius
        [-99.2840423, 19.3906797, "Mexico City", "https://placeimg.com/440/484/arc", "http://act.is"], // Mexico City
        [72.7407565, 19.0821976, "Mumbai", "https://placeimg.com/646/505/arc", "http://act.is"], // Mumbai
        [36.7069666, -1.303205, "Nairobi", "https://placeimg.com/666/666/arc", "http://act.is"], // Nairobi
        [-74.2605525, 40.6971478, "New York", "https://placeimg.com/680/440/arc", "http://act.is"], // New York
        [-46.8761786, -23.6821592, "Sao Paulo", "https://placeimg.com/555/444/arc", "http://act.is"], // Sao Paulo
        [126.8491222, 37.5650168, "Seoul", "https://placeimg.com/777/777/arc", "http://act.is"], // Seoul
        [120.9149227, 31.2231278, "Shanghai", "https://placeimg.com/555/555/arc", "http://act.is"], // Shanghai
        [103.7038198, 1.3139961, "Singapore", "https://placeimg.com/645/580/arc", "http://act.is"], // Singapore
    ];

    // preload images
    // for (let i = 0; i < locale.length; i++) {
    //     new Image().src = locale[i][3];
    //     console.log("Image pre-loaded: " + locale[i][3]);
    // }

    // draw circles at locale locations
    g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(locale).enter()
    .append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return (d[4]); })
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return (projection(d)[0] - 14); })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return (projection(d)[1] - 14); })
    .attr("data-city", function (d) { return (d)[2]; })
    .attr("width", "28px")
    .attr("height", "28px")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { 
        let rotate = 45;
        let x = projection(d)[0];
        let y = projection(d)[1];
        let transform = "rotate (" + rotate + " " + x + " " + y + ")"
        return transform;
        })
    .attr("fill", "#fc511f")
    // hover effects
    .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
        let city = d[2];
        let image = d[3];
        // dot bounce
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration('1000')
            .ease(d3.easeElastic) 
            .attr("width", "50px")
            .attr("height", "50px")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return (projection(d)[0] - 25); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return (projection(d)[1] - 25); })
        // popup appear
        officePop.transition()
            .duration('150')
            .style("opacity", 1);
        // console.log(this);
        officePop
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 70) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 170) + "px");
        officePopImage
            // .attr("src", image);
        officePopTitle
            .html("<span>" + city + "</span>" + "<span style='font-family: serif; font-size: 12px;'>&#9658;</span>");
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
        // dot shrink
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration('100')
            .attr("width", "28px")
            .attr("height", "28px")
            .attr("x", function (d) { return (projection(d)[0] - 14); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return (projection(d)[1] - 14); })
        // popup disappear
        officePop
            .style("left", "-140px")
            .style("top", "0px");
        officePop.transition()
            .duration('100')
            .style("opacity", 0);
    })
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any output on the console? In the code for Wordpress you dropped the lines for the error logging in the json callback.

Comment: Hey @deristnochda - yeah when the error logging is in there is no errors in the console, frustratingly. I'm wondering if CORS could cause this and if so why it wouldn't throw an error

Comment: @deristnochda to answer - no output in the console after adding the error logging back.

Comment: I would also expect an error on the console if file access was blocked due to CORS. But that’s not really my range of expertise. You could try fetching that file without the d3 helper method just to be sure.